# Subquery ORDER BY and LIMIT not working in knex (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have the following query:

```
// Need a subquery to limit to 1 update
const subQuery = queryBuilder => queryBuilder
  .forUpdate()
  .where('won', false)
  .where('win_after', '<=', knex.fn.now())
  .orderBy('priority', 'desc')
  .limit(1);

knex('prizes')
  .forUpdate()
  .where(subQuery)
  .update({
    won_at: knex.fn.now(),
    won: true,
  })
  .returning('*');
```

The query I'm trying to buid is

```
UPDATE 
  "prizes" 
SET 
  "won_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  "won" = $1 
WHERE 
  (
    SELECT * FROM "prizes"
    WHERE "won" = $2 
    AND "win_after" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ORDER BY "priority"
    LIMIT 1
  )
returning *
```

I'm trying to find one prize (only 1) to update and mark as one (sorting by prize priority).

The generated query is

```
update "prizes" set "won_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "won" = $1 where ("won" = $2 and "win_after" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) returning * trx4
```

(See [this knex playground link](https://dgadelha.github.io/knex-playground/#Ly8gTmVlZCBhIHN1YnF1ZXJ5IHRvIGxpbWl0IHRvIDEgdXBkYXRlCmNvbnN0IHN1YlF1ZXJ5ID0gcXVlcnlCdWlsZGVyID0+IHF1ZXJ5QnVpbGRlcgogIC5mb3JVcGRhdGUoKQogIC53aGVyZSgnd29uJywgZmFsc2UpCiAgLndoZXJlKCd3aW5fYWZ0ZXInLCAnPD0nLCBrbmV4LmZuLm5vdygpKQogIC5vcmRlckJ5KCdwcmlvcml0eScsICdkZXNjJykKICAubGltaXQoMSk7CgprbmV4KCdwcml6ZXMnKQogIC5mb3JVcGRhdGUoKQogIC53aGVyZShzdWJRdWVyeSkKICAudXBkYXRlKHsKICAgIHdvbl9hdDoga25leC5mbi5ub3coKSwKICAgIHdvbjogdHJ1ZSwKICB9KQogIC5yZXR1cm5pbmcoJyonKTs=))

So it's missing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. Still a novice with knex and pg, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: The query you want is invalid.  syntax error at trx2, and then "ERROR:  subquery must return only one column"

Comment: Thanks, forgot to remove the extra transaction (trx2) omitted there for clarity. After reading a bit more since I asked the question, I understand I'll have to use CTEs to do what I want (update at most 1 result) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was tring to implement [CTEs (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) but after all I managed to do without:

```
// Need a subquery to limit to 1 update
const subQuery = db<Prize>('prizes')
  .select('uuid')
  .forUpdate()
  .whereNot('won', true)
  .where('win_after', '<=', db.fn.now())
  .orderBy('priority', 'desc')
  .first()

return db<Prize>('prizes')
  .transacting(trx)
  .where('uuid', subQuery)
  .update({
    won_at: db.fn.now(),
    won: true,
  })
  .returning('*');
});
```

Which translates to the following SQL:

```
update
  "prizes"
set
  "won_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  "won" = true
where
  "uuid" = (
    select
      "uuid"
    from
      "prizes"
    where
      not "won" = true
      and "win_after" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    order by
      "priority" desc
    limit
      1 for
    update
  ) returning *
```

Here is the [knex playground](https://dgadelha.github.io/knex-playground/#Ly8gTmVlZCBhIHN1YnF1ZXJ5IHRvIGxpbWl0IHRvIDEgdXBkYXRlCmNvbnN0IHN1YlF1ZXJ5ID0ga25leCgncHJpemVzJykKICAuc2VsZWN0KCd1dWlkJykKICAuZm9yVXBkYXRlKCkKICAud2hlcmVOb3QoJ3dvbicsIHRydWUpCiAgLndoZXJlKCd3aW5fYWZ0ZXInLCAnPD0nLCBrbmV4LmZuLm5vdygpKQogIC5vcmRlckJ5KCdwcmlvcml0eScsICdkZXNjJykKICAuZmlyc3QoKQoKa25leCgncHJpemVzJykKICAudXBkYXRlKHsKICAgIHdvbl9hdDoga25leC5mbi5ub3coKSwKICAgIHdvbjogdHJ1ZSwKICB9KQogIC53aGVyZSgndXVpZCcsIHN1YlF1ZXJ5KQogIC5yZXR1cm5pbmcoJyonKTs=).